# Why this drop down list goes out of window

Tags: jquery, html, css

Why does this drop down list goes out of the window?

I am using HTML + CSS3 + jQuery, I tried to change the position of the drop-down list elements to `fixed` and `top:0px` but it doesn't help!

I can't get the point why the list goes out of the page, so you waiting for your best solution regarding this problem.

Kindly I need your assistance

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.menu').children().mouseenter(function(){


 $('.menu').children(this).find('div').fadeIn(500);


})

$('.menu').children().mouseleave(function(){


 $('.menu').children(this).find('div').fadeOut(500);


})

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu">

  <div class="element">
      Smaller
      <div>Paragraph 1</div>
      <div>Paragraph 1</div>
      <div>Paragraph 1</div>
      <div>Paragraph 1</div>

  </div>

</div>


    <script src='jquery-3.4.1.min.js'></script>
    <script src='jquery.js'></script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.menu').children().mouseenter(function(){


 $('.menu').children(this).find('div').fadeIn(500);


})

$('.menu').children().mouseleave(function(){


 $('.menu').children(this).find('div').fadeOut(500);


})

})
```

```css
.menu
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #08298A;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
}

.element 
{
  background-color: #0A0A2A;
  top: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.element div
{
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #045FB4;
  border: 1px solid white;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">

  <div class="element">
      Smaller
      <div>Paragraph 1</div>
      <div>Paragraph 1</div>
      <div>Paragraph 1</div>
      <div>Paragraph 1</div>

  </div>

</div>
```

```
<div class="menu">

  <div class="element">
      Smaller
      <div>Paragraph 1</div>
      <div>Paragraph 1</div>
      <div>Paragraph 1</div>
      <div>Paragraph 1</div>

  </div>

</div>



$(document).ready(function(){

$('.menu').children().mouseenter(function(){


$('.menu').children(this).find('div').fadeIn(500);


})

$('.menu').children().mouseleave(function(){


$('.menu').children(this).find('div').fadeOut(500);


})

})
```

Comment: Try `margin-top: 0;` in the div style

Answer (score 1):

It's the `align-items: center` in your .menu rule. That in combination with `display: flex` means it will try to center the child .element vertically. And in this case there's not enough room so a portion of it is displayed off screen.